# Steps to perform document clustering using k-means algorithm in java

Tags: java

I need steps to perform document clustering using k-means algorithm in java. 
It will be very useful for me to provide the steps easily. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.sourcecodesworld.com/source/show.asp?ScriptID=807

Answer (score 3):

You need to count the words in each document and make a feature generally called bag of words. Before that you need to remove stop words(very common but not giving much information like the, a etc). You can generally take top n common words from your document. Count the frequency of these words and store them in n dimensional vector.

For distance measure you can use cosine vector.

Here is a simple algorithm for 2 mean for 1 dimensional data points. you can extend it to k mean and n dimensional data point easily. Let me know if you want n dim implementation.

```
double[] x = {1,2,2.5,3,3.5,4,4.5,5,7,8,8.5,9,9.5,10};
```

double[] center = new int[2];
double[] precenter = new int[2];
ArrayList[] cluster = new ArrayList[2];

//generate 2 random number from 0 to x.length without replacement
int rand = new int[2];
Random rand = new Random();
rand[0] = rand.nextInt(x.length + 1);
rand[1] = rand.nextInt(x.length + 1);

while(rand[0] == rand[1] ){
  rand[1] = rand.nextInt(x.length + 1);
}
center[0] = x[rand[0]];
center[1] = x[rand[1]];
//there is a better way to generate k random number (w/o replacement) just search.

do{
  cluster[0].clear();
  cluster[1].clear();
  for(int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i){
          if(abs(x[i]-center1[0]) <= abs(x[i]-center1[1])){
             cluster[0].add(x[i]);
          }
          else{
             cluster[0].add(x[i]);
          }
          precenter[0] = center[0];
          precenter[1] = center[1];
          center[0] = mean(cluster[0]);
          center[1] = mean(cluster[1]);
 }
} while(precenter[0] != center[0] && precenter[1] != center[1]);

double mean(ArrayList list){
    double mean = 0;
    double sum = 0;
    for(int index=0;index
}

The cluster[0] and cluster [1] contain points in the clusters and center[0], center[1] are the 2 means.
you need to do some debugging because I have written the code in R and just converted it into java for you :)

Comment: Hi Atul,
Thanks for your reply.
My work till now :
Removed stop words
Frequency count for each word in whole documents
Then how to perform the cluster using k-means.Please suggest ideas

Comment: In your case each point would be an n-dimensional vectors of word frequency and the Euclid distance would be replaced by cosine similarity. 

These are too much to implement. You can have a look at Manhout. Here is the link https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAHOUT/K-Means+Clustering
It has simple java classes to implement k-mean clustering with examples. You can run it on your machine and the same code would run on hadoop cluster also.

Some code using manhout k mean on netflix data here:
http://code.google.com/p/canopy-clustering/

Answer (score 1):

Does [this](http://www.sourcecodesworld.com/source/show.asp?ScriptID=807) help you? Also the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) article has some links to implementations in other languages ready to be ported to java.

Steps of the algorithm:

1. Define the number of clusters you want to have
2. Distribute the points radomly in your problem space.
3. Link every observation to the nearest point.
4. calculate the center of mass for each cluster and place the point into the middle.
5. Link the points again to the centerpoints and repeat until the points dont move any more.

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to cluster the documents based on?  If it's by similarity you'll need to do some natural language processing first, and then you'll need a metric (some kind of assignment algorithm) to place the documents into clusters (crp works and is relatively straight forward).

The hardest part will be the NLP (language processing) if you're not clustering them based on something like "length".  I can provide more info on all of these, but I won't dive down the rabbit hole if you don't need it.

Comment: My point here is that k-means is the easy part... you can't just throw documents at it, they're not feature vectors yet.

Comment: Hi ikline,

My work till now :

REmove stop words
Frequency count for each word in whole documents
Then how to perform the cluster using k-means.Please suggest ideas

Comment: First you need a definition for your clusters-  I would use some kind of assignment algorithm on your word frequencies to find out which ones hang together often, and then use k means to assign the documents to the "clusters"